# Odoo 14 API - No module named xmlrpc.client

Tags: python-3.x, api, odoo-14, xmlrpcclient

Hello i'm trying the External API of Odoo so i'm trying something but i have an error when i try to launch my main.py.

```py
import xmlrpc.client


info = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('https://demo.odoo.com/start').start()
url, db, username, password = \
     info['host'], info['database'], info['user'], info['password']
common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
common.version()
```

But when i launch this file i have this output :

```sh
python main.py                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
      import xmlrpc.client
ImportError: No module named xmlrpc.client
```

Can someone help me please ? Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I'll answer myself...

**The problem was my Python default version.**

I had Python2.7 et Python3.8, but the priority was set to :

> Python2.7 as "2" (hight priority)

AND

> Python3.8 as "1" (low priority)

so i had to change the priority of both by this command :

```
 update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
 update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 2
```